# Wrong reputation calculation in achievements dialog

Tags: bug, reputation, top-bar, achievements-dialog

Looks like there is something wrong with reputation calculation:

> [image: rep]

+2*5 -6*2 = -2...   why there is +6 in reputation popup?

As @Catija said in comment calculation is OK in the profile:

> [image: profile]

Perhaps the issue is in the top-bar.

Comment: The top bar stopped reporting rep changes. Your profile is correct. I noticed the same issue but it's definitely a top bar only problem.

Comment: ... or, more accurately, it relates to the achievements dropdown generally. I'm not seeing the rep updates in the achievements pane in the iOS app, either.

Comment: Weird... they're back now but haven't caught up the missing ones. I received an upvote just now and got an alert but the achievements went from 90 to 95, should be 105.

Comment: I just noticed the same thing. I have an [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/342123/11683) with 7 upvotes, but only +20 reputation attributed to that answer in the drop-down. However, the reputation on my profile page is correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stack Overflow "Achievements tab" displaying incorrect reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303767/stack-overflow-achievements-tab-displaying-incorrect-reputation)

Comment: @CarInsurance no, there is really no reason to close this as duplicate of newer bug report, which is not written better.

Comment: @ShadowWizard the newer one gives a little context and a workaround.

Comment: @CarInsurance the workaround is wrong.

Comment: Noticed the same back on TWP. My TWP reputation is strange, but the SO rep I did today has no problem. Already logged out and in and still same problems. Wrote a Meta post [here](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4953/rep-gained-not-showing-on-achievements-dropdown-but-does-in-rep-tab) if it helps