# Stack Overflow "Achievements tab" displaying incorrect reputation

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page, achievements-dialog

### Brief

Today I ran across an odd issue in Stack Overflow. My reputation doesn't match between my *Profile* page to the *Achievements* tab!

I know for a fact that my *Profile* page is displaying correct information. As you can see from the images below, my *Profile* page is displaying 135 reputation, while the *Achievements* tab is showing only 75

**Profile page**

[image: Profile page reputation]

**Achievements tab**

[image: Achievements tab reputation]

#### How I managed this?

Honestly, I have no idea.

My computer was left logged into my account over the weekend (as I usually do) and I started posting answers again today. Everything seemed fine until I realized one of my answers were accepted but I hadn't received a notification in the *Achievements* tab. Comments work fine (notifications are sent), but *Achievements* doesn't display all the reputation I've received today.

#### How I somewhat solved it

Naturally, my first reaction was to logout and log back in. *Maybe this would solve it?* Upon logging back in the reputation I had gained prior to this action still doesn't show up, but any reputation gained after the logout/login procedure does. I also checked on another device (my phone - using the app) and the reputation in *Achievements* doesn't match.

I'm assuming this is a bug, but how can I fix this so that my *Achievements* tab displays the correct information?

Comment: So I guess I'm not the only one to report this bug in the last hour @CarInsurance

Comment: Yeah, two others noticed. On second thought, actually, I think you deserve to be the canonical.

Comment: @alexolut we're going back and forth between my question being marked a duplicate of that one and vice-versa, can someone just pick one or the other as a duplicate? I don't care which but it's a see-saw right now. CarInsurance felt the other should be duplicate of mine after he has marked mine as a duplicate of it and then retracted it. Now you've added it back and it's just going in circles.

Comment: Logging out and back in again was irrelevant. The system simply started reporting rep to the top bar again. See my comment on alexolut's question. It was only failing to report reputation to the top bar for about an hour.

Comment: @Catija The timing of me logging in and out must have been highly coincidental then. Regardless it is still possible that this helped with the resolution of this issue

Comment: ... I don't think that *you* logging in and out fixed everyone's top bar... but if you want to believe that. Feel free.

Comment: @Catija I meant resolved the issue for *me* haha I’m not that naive

Comment: Also experiencing this on The Workplace: Wrote a [Meta](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4953/rep-gained-not-showing-on-achievements-dropdown-but-does-in-rep-tab) post about it

Comment: Logged out and in and it did not solve the issue for me. In my case, I had earned rep on two sites today (TWP and SO). The SO rep was fine, but my TWP rep was odd, and did not match the one on my reputation tab on my profile.